# Twilio Studio Switch Transition Order Checking

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I have a Split that has multiple transitions based upon a single value.  I need to know what order the transitions are evaluated.  Is it top to bottom when viewing the transitions, random, or what?  I could break this up into multiple Splits, but it would be much more compact to have a single Split.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently there is no publicly available ordering of the split conditions. I would recommend making sure your conditions are mutually exclusive or to follow the path of more than one split if that's not possible.

Comment: Thank you.  I decided that relying on the ordering was dangerous as it could change in the future, and it was less than obvious, so I broke it out into multiple splits.